# Symfony 3 + FOSUserBundle - Overriding template

Tags: templates, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have installed Symfony 3.2 and FOSUser dev-master.
I would like to override FOSUser templates in my custom bundle using my bundle as child of FOSUserBundle.

Unfortunatelly this not works.. This overriding way works correctly for controllers, but not for templates.. when I used first way to overriding templates (in app/Resources...) it worked, but second way described in documentations (custom bundle) not works..

Does somebody know why?

Doc link: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html

I see that in doc for the newest version second way is there, but it isn't described like it was in older version (1.3)..

is it removed in the newest version (2.0) ?

Unfortunatelly, I can't use older FOSUser version for Symfony 3... ;/

Comment: Add the code you are using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574435/overriding-fosuserbundles-templates-from-inheritance