# Overriding FOSUserBundle's templates from inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, overriding, symfony, fosuserbundle

As the title suggests I'm trying to customize FOSUserBundle's templates with my own ones. But it doesn't work at all. I tried everything as stated in every posts I found, proofread everything, cleared the cache thousands of times, still not working.

Bundle class with getParent :

```
<?php
// src/PLL/UserBundle/PLLUserBundle.php

namespace PLL\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class PLLUserBundle extends Bundle
{
  public function getParent()
  {
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
  }
}
?>
```

The template that should override the fos' one :

```
{# src/PLL/UserBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig #}

{% extends "PLLCoreBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}

  {% for key, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      <div class="alert alert-{{ key }}">
        {{ message|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% block fos_user_content %}
  {% endblock fos_user_content %}

{% endblock %}
```

FOS' template, the one that is actually being used by Symfony :

```
{# vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig #}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
                {{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': app.user.username}, 'FOSUserBundle') }} |
                <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">
                    {{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
                </a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">{{ 'layout.login'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        {% if app.request.hasPreviousSession %}
            {% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="flash-{{ type }}">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        <div>
            {% block fos_user_content %}
            {% endblock fos_user_content %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Going to /web/app_dev.php/login still shows the FOS' layout, even after deleting the cache over and over again. Either with a php bin/console cache:clear, or deleting "by hand" the var folder in my project's root. Even deleted my browser's cache.

Not to mention, extending "PLLCoreBundle::layout.html.twig" works perfectly fine in any other views on my website. So I don't think it comes from an error in my twig template.

In case they can be of any help,

My security.yml file :

```
// app/config/security.yml

security:
[...]
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: true
            provider: main
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
            logout:
                path:    fos_user_security_logout
                target:  /platform
[...]
```

The app's routing file :

```
// app/config/routing.yml

[...]

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

So... What am I missing ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572723/symfony-3-fosuserbundle-overriding-template

Comment: But are templates that don't work or only one? I don't understand

Comment: @Aerendir FOSUserBundle's default templates are working. My template for everything else on the website are working. The only thing not working is my custom templates not overriding FOS' one, so when I want to go to on my /login page or /register I always get to the FOS' templates and can't get mine to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to override FOSUserBundle's templates, like the one for login, or the one for register, and so on.

In order to do that, you need to copy, manually, all the dirs/files from `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user_bundle/Resources/views` into `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views`.

And then, if you want to modify the template for the login page, then you can can put your own template in the `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login_content.html.twig`.

Comment: So, does it mean that we can't override templates with inheritance anymore, and we have to use the app/Resources method ?

Comment: Yes, you can use inheritance too. For that, you must use the `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig`. And this `layout.html.twig` can, for example, inherit from `base.html.twig` the `bootstrap` css framework. Or anything else you might want. The thing is that all templates (eg. `Security/login.html.twig` or `Registration/register.html.twig`) inherit from this `layout.html.twig`. Just play around a little bit with the templates you've copied, and you'll figure out how things work.

Comment: Okay. I thought it was possible to override them with templates directly from a bundle which inherits from FOSUserBundle with the getParent() method. I'll work with the app/Resources folder then. Thanks.

Comment: @Kishlin Glad to hear that.