# Symfony - overwrite FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to overwrite the layout of FOSUserBundle from inside my own bundle (MV\UserBundle). I have tried to extend FOSUserBundle from my bundle like so :

```
<?php

namespace MV\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class MVUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

and to place my layout in src/MV/UserBundle/Ressources/views/layout.html.twig as stated in the documentation but I can't get it to display my layout.

I have also tried to clear the cache with `php bin/console cache:clear` but I got no results.

I managed to get it to work by placing my view in app/Ressources/FOSUserBundle/layout.html.twig but I would like to have it inside my bundle.

I am using Symfony3 and friendsofsymfony/user-bundle dev-master.

Answer (score 0):

To override one or more FOSUserBundle's templates, copy all the folders and files from `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user_bundle/Resources/views` into `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views` directory. I guess this should work well even if you copy them into a bundle (eg. `AppBundle/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views`).

You should use the search functionality more ofter, as this question was already answered *[today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574435/overriding-fosuserbundles-templates-from-inheritance/41588153)*.

Comment: The documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html says that I am not obliged to use the app/Ressource folder but that I can create a child bundle - as I did but it is not working

Comment: There is stated as well: `This method is more complicated than the one outlined above. Unless you are planning to override the controllers as well as the templates, it is recommended that you use the other method.` So you want to override the controllers as well, or just the templates? In the OP you say you want to override the layout. So the `a` option is more suited for your needs.